# Problem with removing doubles

Tags: objects, armature

[image]
So I want connect my skeleton with objects but when I try to do it blender showing me "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones", I decided to remove doubles but shortcut "W" is changing tools, is there another ways to remove doubles?

Comment: Alt+M to merge, then use "by distance".

Comment: Yaay, ty, u saved my project :)